# how to make text to get invisible from the page after a button click

Tags: c#, asp.net, buttonclick

I am developing a webpage in which I want to make text to get invisible after a button click and make gridview to be visible. In the page I have textboxes and button also, but those things can be made invisible by using "textbox.visible = false" and "button.visible = false" but I dont understand how to make the text to get invisible.
The design of the page is as shown below :
[image]

I want to make those "Search details", "Account number" and "Scriptname" to be invisible and only gridview to be visible after the button click ;
Please suggest how to do it.

Comment: Its hard to help you without the markup. But you could put all except that grid into an asp:panel and make the panel invisible.

Comment: @BgI86 : Thank u dude.. I will definately try that

Comment: Ever heard of JQuery? Take a look at the documentation. You might want to consider adding this behavior on the client side.  http://api.jquery.com/hide/

Comment: @akemp : Ok thank u :)

Comment: is it possible to make the text to disappear using the c# code itself??

Comment: Place your code inside <asp:Panel> on Click server side make Panel.visible =false;

Comment: @ManishGoswami : thanks Manish , write your answer so that I can close question.

Comment: @ImadoddinIbnAlauddin : thank u, i have done the modification in the markup... see the answer below..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include all the controls in an ASP.NET Panel control and hide\show them in code behind based on condition:-

```
<asp:Panel ID="SearchPanel" runat="server">
    <%--put all the controls here--%>
</asp:Panel>
```

Then in code behind just use the panel control's id and change is visibility:-

```
SearchPanel.Visible = true;
SearchPanel.Visible = false;
```

Answer (score 1):

By using panel, I was able to solve the problem. 
HTML code of the page will be :

Account Number

Scriptname

Market value      
    
    
    
                 
    
    
    
In code behind page I change visibility of panel to false. (C# code is shown below)

```
Panel1.Visible = false;
```

Comment: good. next time remember to show your markup too.in your Question :)

Comment: sure @ManishGoswami, I will not forget to add next time, but here I felt it was unnecessary so did not shared